# If all the Child Category check-boxes are Selected Then Parent checkbox Should be selected Automatically

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code: I've created the checkboxes for parent and child. I'm looking for Javascript validation for the below code. When I select the single child the parent checkbox is selecting but I'want to select all the child checkboxes then only the parent should select.

```
<label>Product Category:</label>
  <div class="wk_field wk_category">
    <div class="wk_for_validation">
      <div id="wk_category_label">CATEGORIES</div>
      <div class="wk_cat_container" style="margin-left:0px;">
        <span class="wk_minus"> </span>
        <span class="wk_foldersign"></span>
        <span class="wk_elements wk_cat_name">Gold</span>
        <input class="wk_elements" type="checkbox" value="3" name="category[]" id="3">
      </div>
      <div class="wk_removable wk_cat_container" style="margin-left: 20px;">
        <span class="wk_no"></span>
        <span class="wk_foldersign"></span>
        <span class="wk_elements wk_cat_name">Earrings</span>
        <input class="wk_elements" type="checkbox" value="27" name="category[]" data-parent=3 >
      </div>
      <div class="wk_removable wk_cat_container" style="margin-left: 20px;">
        <span class="wk_minusend"></span>
        <span class="wk_foldersign"></span>
        <span class="wk_elements wk_cat_name">Rings</span>
        <input class="wk_elements" type="checkbox" value="26" name="category[]" data-parent=3 id="26">
      </div>
      <div class="wk_removable wk_cat_container" style="margin-left: 20px;">
        <span class="wk_minusend"></span>
        <span class="wk_foldersign"></span>
        <span class="wk_elements wk_cat_name">bangles</span>
        <input class="wk_elements" type="checkbox" value="26" name="category[]" data-parent=3 id="26">
      </div>
```

```
var cb_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, len = cb_list.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (cb_list[i].type === 'checkbox') {
        cb_list[i].onclick = function(i) {
            return function() {
                checkParent(this);
            }
        }(i);
    }
}

function checkParent(ele) {
    var idparent = ele.getAttribute('data-parent');
    if (idparent) {
        var parent = document.getElementById(idparent);
        if (ele.checked === true) parent.checked = true;
        checkParent(parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you make any attempts to achieve what you want? Your question looks more like a task now.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this javscript code:var cb_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0, len=cb_list.length; i<len; i++) {
    if ( cb_list[i].type === 'checkbox' ) {
        cb_list[i].onclick = function(i) {
            return function(){
                checkParent(this);
              }
        }(i);
    }
}

function checkParent(ele) {
  var idparent = ele.getAttribute('data-parent');
  if(idparent){
   var parent = document.getElementById(idparent);
    if (ele.checked === true) parent.checked = true;
    checkParent(parent);
  }
}

Comment: you can use jstree for this kind of functionality. https://www.jstree.com/

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is in jQuery

/* Single checkbox at top to select all child checkboxs */

```
$('#parent_checkbox').on('click', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.child_check').each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        });
    } else {
        $('.child_check').each(function () {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});
```

/* check all child checkbox are selected to select the parent checkbox  */

```
$(document).on('click', '.child_check', function () {
    if ($('.child_check:checked').length === $('.child_check').length) {
        $('#parent_checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#parent_checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time and patience. Can you do it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectall" id="parent_checkbox" class="selectall"/></td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ckbox[]" id="1" class="child_check" value="1" onclick="check()" /></td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ckbox[]" id="2" class="child_check" value="2" onclick="check()" /></td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ckbox[]" id="3" class="child_check" value="3" onclick="check()" /></td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ckbox[]" id="4" class="child_check" value="4" onclick="check()" /></td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ckbox[]" id="5" class="child_check" value="5" onclick="check()" /></td>    
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check(){
            var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('ckbox[]');
            var ln = 0;
            for(var i=0; i< checkbox.length; i++) { //check for child checkboxes
            if(checkbox[i].checked)
                ln++
            }

            //select parent if all child are checked
            var all = document.getElementsByName('ckbox[]');
            var num    = all.length;        

            if(ln == num){
                document.getElementById("parent_checkbox").checked = true;
            }else{
                document.getElementById("parent_checkbox").checked = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </html>
```